# Gremlin: is it possible to filter on optional properties? (graph database is Neptune)

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have a graph with a single vertex:

gremlin> g.V().valueMap(true)

==>{id=a, x=[foo], label=vertex}

The vertex can be found in the following query:

gremlin> g.V().has('x', 'foo')

==>v[a]

However, I would like to modify the above query with the additional match constraint: match the vertex if it does not have property "y", or if the vertex does have property "y" and the value for property "y" equals "bar".

I have constructed the following query.

g.V().has('x', 'foo').or(__.hasNot('y'), __.has('y', 'bar'))

The query returns no matching vertices.   So, I think I am looking for something equivalent to "IFNULL()" in mysql.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Joel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your `or()` filter, it should just work.

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.addV().property(id, 'a').property('x', 'foo').iterate()
gremlin> g.V().has('x', 'foo').or(__.hasNot('y'), __.has('y', 'bar'))
==>v[a]
```

Alternatively you can check that there's no `y` value that is not `bar`.

```
gremlin> g.V().has('x', 'foo').not(__.values('y').is(neq('bar')))
==>v[a]
```

However, double negations tend to be confusing, so I would just go with `or()`.

Comment: Yikes!  it does work with TinkerGraph, but not with my actual graph database (Neptune).  Thoughts?

Comment: What about the double negation? I assume this will work.

Comment: Yes, the double-negation worked, thanks!

-- but  g.V().has('x', 'foo').or(__.hasNot('y'), __.has('y', 'bar')) does not work.

Comment: Spoke with aws about this, they confirmed that this is a known bug in Neptune.  They suggested the following work-around: g.V().has('x', 'foo').union(__.hasNot('y'), __.has('y', 'bar')) (using UNION instead of OR)